# protected variables in derived class

Tags: c++

In my project I have some structure like this:

```
template <typename T>
class deque
{
// ...
    class MyIterator
    {
    protected:
        T* p;

    public: 
        MyIterator(T* x)
        : p(x)
        {
        }
    };

    class Iterator: public MyIterator
    {
    public: 
        Iterator(T* x)
        : MyIterator(x)
        {
        }

        T* foo() { return p; }
    };
};
```

I keep getting an error

```
`In member function 'foo' error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
         return p`
```

I've tried to change `p` from `protected` to `public`, but this did not help. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try `return this->p;` ?

Comment: @Slava it worked! thanks! Can you sir, please, pos this as an answer and I'll accept this. And please, could you explain why `this->` needed? I didn't need this in some regular classes with inherit

Comment: I tried to compile your code and it worked fine without any modification (Windows 8, VS 2013).

Comment: @vizhanyolajos: That's because VS plays fast and loose with the name lookup rules. A compiler following the language standard wouldn't find a name in a context that depends on the value of a template parameter, since that value isn't known until the template is instantiated.